# Appending + Removing Postgres Text Array elements. Resulting in massive table sizes

Tags: arrays, postgresql

```
UPDATE db.table SET logs = array_prepend('some things happened', logs[0:1000]) WHERE id = 'foo';
```

This query simply prepends text to a text array, and removes elements from the array and limits the array to 1,000 elements. It works, but the table size on the disk rapidly swells to multiple GB (The table should only be around 150MB). Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in PostgreSQL? I'm running PostgreSQL 11.9. If I don't run a full vacuum, PostgreSQL will eventually use up all available disk space.

This query is for a turn-based game, and it stores logs about what's happening to the player for debugging purposes.

Comment: This would be a lot more efficient in a properly normalized data model

Comment: Row versions are written in full, so every time you do an UPDATE, it writes the entire contents of that array (+ all the other columns) again. The table will re-use the space where the old row versions were stored, but usually not immediately; this will depend on your autovacuum settings, and whether there are any long-running transactions open against the DB. If you need to avoid having a bloated table, you need to normalize that array column as a separate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The space is only cleared by vacuum/autovacuum. However there's actually not a huge cost to having that used space around, as Postgres will reuse it if it runs short on disk space.

Part of the issue is that modifying a column value requires rewriting the entire row (or in this case, your column is probably getting TOASTed, so rewriting the pointer to the TOAST table and writing a new value in the TOAST table), so each update you do rewrites everything you have stored. For large values this adds up quickly.

If you're really worried about it I think normalizing this might be a good choice, or you could switch to storing this data in something better designed for append only data. Or you could use an FDW designed for storing append only data like this outside the normal storage mechanisms, usually as a file on disk.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking; Just move the logs to their own table.